Iterate a list through FOR loop and concat resulting data from function to a pd dataframe
This is my code:
    list = ["base1", "base2", "base3"]
    dfs = []
    for x in list:
        _data = function(x)
        df = dfs.append(_data)
df_master = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

The code only generated the last values of the list base3. This is my attempt and generating all values but I get an error.
What I want:
For each value in the list ran through the function, the function generate a dataframe of at least 100 rows with same headers. I want to concat all of these results. I have over 20 values in my list.
Thanks!

So what's the problem with this code?

What did you come up with? where is the definition of function(x)?

df_master = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True) should be outside of the loop, and df = dfs.append(_data) should just be dfs.append(_data)

@mozway I still get the last results from base3. I want all the results. Thanks!

@MariaK presently the code only generates the results from the base3 and over writes the results from base1 and base2. Thanks

VERY SORRY GUYS! The program runs fine, I was comparing partial results to my full dataframe. smh.

@user7446890 then please delete this question

You shouldn't call a list list, because that's a Python builtin. The rest can be reduced to a list comprehension.
your_list = ["base1", "base2", "base3"]
df_master = pd.concat([function(x) for x in your_list], ignore_index=True)


As You stated, with the assumption that your function  takes a string as an argument and returns a dataframe, we could decide to create a list of dataframe by using the map() method to execute the function taking each string in the list as an argument ..
my_list= ["base1", "base2", "base3"]
df_list= list(map(function,my_list))
master_df=pd.concat(df_list,ignore_index=True)
master_df.head()

